# Extract data from table with different amount of spaces in between in Python

Tags: python, extract

I want to extract data from a .txt file that looks like this in Python:

```
Pennsylvania       (105161,985645)     189562.58   0
California       (586253,566851)     556064.21   0
Kentucky       (875956,213560)     985022.85   1
Oklahoma       (485010,506222)     521446.15   0
```

The number of spaces between two particular columns are always the same but they differ from time to time. There are no spaces within the column entries themselves.

I want to pool all entries of one row into a tupel and I want to put all the tupels into a list. How can I extract the entries from the file?

I tried working with line.split but I was not sure how to use it since the number of spaces between the columns differ.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You could try using a regex to match whitespace characters until you hit a non whitespace character

Comment: line.split() will work even if you vary number of spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line.split() will work even if you vary the number of spaces.

```
with open("a.txt", "r") as fd:
    myList = []
    for i in fd.readlines():        # iterate over each line
        mytuple = tuple(m for m in i.split())  # generate tuples
        myList.append(mytuple)    # append tuples to list
    print(myList)
```

**output**:

```
[('Pennsylvania', '(105161,985645)', '189562.58', '0'), ('California', '(586253,566851)', '556064.21', '0'), ('Kentucky', '(875956,213560)', '985022.85', '1'), ('Oklahoma', '(485010,506222)', '521446.15', '0')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', header=None, sep="\s+")
```

Output:

```
              0                1          2  3
0  Pennsylvania  (105161,985645)  189562.58  0
1    California  (586253,566851)  556064.21  0
2      Kentucky  (875956,213560)  985022.85  1
3      Oklahoma  (485010,506222)  521446.15  0
```